# How should we implement utility/helper modules in C++?

Tags: c++

1) utility class, use only static methods, block copying and creation

```
class myUtils
{
public:
    static void utilFunc();
    static void utilGreatFunc();

private:
    utils() { } // block creation
    utils(const utils &) { }
    ~utils() { }
}
```

2) use namespace

```
namespace myUtils 
{
    void utilFunc();
    void utilGreatFunc();
}
```

what is the best way of doing this? I suppose the namespace way, it is much clearer to me and simpler to write. Or maybe there is some other and better design?

Comment: What about both? Now you can write `utils::utilClass::utilFunc()`! You can never have enough instances of the word "utils" in your code.

Comment: yes, of course, I edited the code and the name of class/namespace. For each library, module there can be separate utility class/namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never use a "utility class with static methods" in C++. That's a Java-ism. Instead, use your second solution and put the functions in a `namespace`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a class with static functions does work, and is a valid way of doing it. That said, it is not very semantic, a namespace with namespace level functions makes more sense. It is also worth pointing out that you can nest namespaces

Comment: TheCoshman: I never tried but you could probably nest inner classes ?

Comment: @BlueTrin: You can. But be aware that those work differently in C++ and Java (not that it matters for `static` methods.)

Answer (score 1):

Several years ago there were lots of discussions about helper classes that you can still search and read. My opinion about this is helper classes are a bad smell almost always (an strong one). They let us see the programmer didn´t know where to put his code and then he created a MyBagOfThingsHelper class which breaks the most basics principles of OOP.

Probably, the most important is the SRP. Ask yourself: which is the responsibility of that MyBagOfThingsHelper class?

What about the strong coupling it creates?

I know this is neither what you asked for nor what you want to read but the best is neither namespaces nor classes but avoid them, avoid them.

Comment: You should never speak in absolutes.

Comment: Sorry for that but I tried to let it clear when I say "My opinion", the rest is just because a lack of enough English.